# How to update jPlayer title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I'm trying to update the display title of a jPlayer object (encircled in red), after the jPlayer object has already been instantiated with a different audio file.

[image: jPlayer object example]

I'm using the following code, which doesn't seem to be working:

```
$("#jplayer-id").jPlayer("setMedia", {
    title: "NEW TITLE"
});
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for [`setMedia`](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-setMedia) setting the title within the jPlayer [`ready`](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-ready) event:

```
$("#jplayer-id").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            title: "NEW TITLE",
        });
    },
});
```

If already initialized, you can use jQuery to target its `jp-title` class.

```
$("#jplayer-id .jp-title").text("NEW TITLE");
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tested this and though it works for setting the title on the original initialization of the jPlayer object, it has no effect on an already initialized jPlayer object. I updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: Okay I wasn't sure if the title needed to be updated through the API. This works. Thanks.

Comment: What about updating the audio file, this would have to be done through the API?

Comment: @reformed What do you mean by `updating the audio file`? 95% chance that it should be done through api.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson What I meant was, say, changing from file1.mp3 to file2.mp3.

Comment: @reformed Yes. use the `setMedia` function for that and use the API for as much as you can as it's already been tested.